# Unused chimney sweats when it rains

Tags: chimney

I have a chimney in my dining room that leaks or sweats. The chimney ends here because I can't find it in the basement. I am assuming that it was sealed at this location. The roof is new, and I also mortar the exposed bricks. I have also sealed around where the chimney and the roof meet, just in case. Now the portion of the chimney that's inside my house was covered with some type of fake plastic brick and painted. I also placed a chimney flue cover to see if that took care of the problem, but no results. Can it be that the material that was used to decorate it is causing the sweating?

Comment: Can you post some pictures that would help us to better understand? What do you mean exactly by 'sweating'? Is there leaking, or just wet spots?

Comment: Yes, pictures of the roof where it meets the chimney on all 4 sides, plus a picture of the top of the chimney.

Comment: Chimney for what? Is there some reason it couldn't be shortened to below the roofline? That's the best fix.